# Receiving TIMEOUT errors attempting to access dockerized rabbitmq from external app

Tags: node.js, docker, rabbitmq, docker-compose

I am currently trying to connect to rabbitmq inside a docker container from a node.js application outside of docker.  Currently, I am receiving TIMEOUT errors when I try to send a message to rabbitmq.

Here are the docker file settings for rabbitmq:

```
rabbitmq:
  container_name: "my_rabbitmq"
  hostname: "rabbitmq"
  tty: true
  image: rabbitmq:management
  ports:
    - 15672:15672
    - 15671:15671
    - 5672:5672
  volumes:
    - /rabbitmq/lib:/var/lib/rabbitmq
    - /rabbitmq/log:/var/log/rabbitmq
    - /rabbitmq/conf:/etc/rabbitmq/
```

I am using the following connection string to access docker:

```
amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672
```

I can access and login to the web admin port at 15672 with no problem and I am currently testing on my local machine(mac os x).  Are there any special network configurations needed to access a dockerized rabbitmq instance from an application that is currently external to docker?

UPDATE:
Not sure if this makes a difference.  When I did a docker-compose logs rabbitmq I see the following entry:

```
    [info] <0.556.0> accepting AMQP connection <0.556.0> (172.20.0.1:58826 -> 172.20.0.2:5672)
    [info] <0.556.0> connection <0.556.0> (172.20.0.1:58826 -> 172.20.0.2:5672): user 'guest' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'
    client unexpectedly closed TCP connection
```

I am not sure what this 172.20.0.2 IP address is.  My connection string is currently set to access localhost and the port, which I mapped using the ports command in the yaml file.

Comment: I guess we'll never know